# If $A$ and $B$ two $n\times n$ matrix such that $AB=BA$, then $\dim(A\cap B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ two $n\times n$ matrix such that $AB=BA$, then my guess is $\dim(A\cap B)\geq \dim AB$. But I am unable to prove this. Any help in this direction is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $A\cap B$ for two matrices? The intersection of their images as linear transformations?

Comment: yes, I mean that intersection of their images as linear transformations..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argue that $\operatorname{im} A$ contains $\operatorname{im}AB$. Then argue that $\operatorname{im}B$ contains $\operatorname{im}BA$. Finally, use that $AB = BA$.

Comment: Thank you..I will work out based on your suggestion..